# Ajax: rest api call give error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, .htaccess, rest

i am trying to understand what is the problem with my code to work with rest api

I am using "EspoCRM" and now i want to start working with the api.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/espocrm/documentation/blob/master/development/api.md) they ask to use: uses Basic Authentication like:

```
"Authorization: Basic " + base64Encode(username + ':' + password)
```

So i try to use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

    var creds = {
    username: "myuser",
    password: "mypass"
};
var credentials = btoa(creds.username + ":" + creds.password);
$.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: false },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic" + credentials);
        return true;
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://crmurl.com/api/v1/App/user',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(json.user.userName);
    }
});

</script>
```

After i use this code i get error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

When i click on the error link i can see all the json data. but because of the error i can't work with the data. no matter what i try.

If i change from `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`

I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://crmurl.com/api/v1/App/user. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I have add in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</IfModule>
```

the json output is:

```
{"user":{"id":"1","name":"Admin","deleted":false,"isAdmin":true,"userName":"admin","password":"xNa3PPcGYcIGQJE4gZi4gnEJ1tv9XF1m7F490qTg.yLPG3Y3QtwRWQq.4RicYIro8akEOZXiWnXzuKg4P4Jnx1","salutationName":"","firstName":"","lastName":"Admin","isActive":true,"title":"","emailAddress":"demo@espocrm.com","phoneNumber":"+44(203)695-03-80","createdAt":"2015-07-11 05:03:05","defaultTeamId":null,"defaultTeamName":null,"teamsIds":[],"teamsNames":{},"avatarName":null,"avatarId":null},"acl":{"table":{"Email":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"EmailAccountScope":true,"EmailTemplate":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Account":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Calendar":true,"Call":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Campaign":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Case":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Contact":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Document":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"DocumentFolder":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Lead":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Meeting":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Opportunity":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"TargetList":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"Task":{"read":"all","edit":"all","delete":"no"},"User":{"read":"all","edit":"no","delete":"no"},"Team":{"read":"all","edit":"no","delete":"no"},"Note":{"read":"all","edit":"own","delete":"own"},"EmailAddress":{"read":"no","edit":"no","delete":"no"},"PhoneNumber":{"read":"no","edit":"no","delete":"no"},"EmailAccount":{"read":"own","edit":"own","delete":"own"},"Role":false},"assignmentPermission":"all","userPermission":"no"},"preferences":{"id":"1","timeZone":"UTC","dateFormat":"MM\/DD\/YYYY","timeFormat":"HH:mm","weekStart":0,"thousandSeparator":",","decimalMark":".","defaultCurrency":"USD","dashboardLayout":[{"name":"My Espo","layout":[[{"name":"Stream","id":"d4"},{"name":"SalesByMonth","id":"d11"},{"name":"SalesPipeline","id":"d12"}],[{"name":"Tasks","id":"d3"},{"name":"OpportunitiesByLeadSource","id":"d14"},{"name":"OpportunitiesByStage","id":"d15"}]]}],"dashletOptions":null,"smtpServer":"","smtpPort":25,"smtpAuth":false,"smtpSecurity":"","language":"es_ES","exportDelimiter":";","receiveAssignmentEmailNotifications":true,"autoFollowEntityTypeList":[],"signature":"<br>","defaultReminders":[]},"token":null}
```

Comment: you say you added CORS header in htaccess, is that on the crmurl.com server?

Comment: @JaromandaX
yes i add this into .htaccess in `crmurl.com` then i get this error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mycrm.com/api/v1/App/user. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: that's correct, you have to be clever when dealing with authorised CORS - stick to the original jsonp implementation which has been solved for you in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

When you make a call with JSON your access is denied as CORS headers is absent. Hence you get the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://crmurl.com/api/v1/App/user. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

This explains the second error. Now, since CORS is not present, JSONP is only way to get the data, which adds CORS headers.

The data you get from AJAX callback is JSON itself. You cannot parse JSON data as `parse` returns JSON data itself. So following code is unnecessary

```
JSON.parse(data);
```

Just assign

```
var json = data;
```

Or use `data` directly. This will solve your first error.

Comment: the problem is the error and not the data.
if i use jsnop the i get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`
if i use json i get this error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://crmurl.com/api/v1/App/user. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.`

Comment: The problem is data only. When you use JSON, essentially you're not allowed on server due to CORS. When you use JSONP, server allows the data and hence you get the data. But since data is JSON itself, you cannot parse again

Comment: The problem is he's described two different errors, you've answered the cause of the first error, but he seems to think you've answered the cause of the second error :p

Comment: OK, lemme rephrase my answer for him then :)

Comment: the first error still appear if i do this:   `success: function (data) {      //console.log(data);
    }`

Comment: You've commented out the wrong line. You've to comment out the problematic line which is ` JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: i have delete all to see if the error appears or not. if i also change to:
`success: function (data) { var json = data; }` i still get the error

Comment: yes the same: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83018/discussion-between-user2413244-and-bikas-vaibhav).